# calling methods using object reference variable

Tags: java, scjp

I read an example of serialization in the SCJP book . Below i have posted that example source code

```
import java.io.*;
public class SerializeDog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collar c = new Collar(3);
        Dog d = new Dog(c, 5);
        System.out.println("before: collar size is "+ d.getCollar().getCollarSize());
        try {
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("testSer.ser"); 
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(d);
            os.close();
        }catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("testSer.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            d = (Dog) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        System.out.println("after: collar size is "**+ d.getCollar().getCollarSize());**
    }
}

class Dog implements Serializable {
    private Collar theCollar;
    private int dogSize;
    public Dog(Collar collar, int size) {
        theCollar = collar;
        dogSize = size;
    }
    public Collar getCollar() { 
        return theCollar; 
    }
}

class Collar implements Serializable {
    private int collarSize;
    public Collar(int size) { 
        collarSize = size; 
    }
    public int getCollarSize() { 
        return collarSize; 
    }
}
```

i want to know when we call `d.getCollar().getCollarSize();`which method gets executed... and please explain what kind of method calling is this in java. how can we use two methods like this.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to know when we call `d.getCollar().getCollarSize();` which
>   method gets executed...

JAVA invoke/execute `gettCollar()` on object `d`, and returns a instance of `Color`. `getCollarSize()` will be invoked on `Collar` instance returned by `d.getColor()` method.

This is how, we chain the method invocation.

You can split the method call into two steps

```
Collar collar = d.getCollar();
int collarSize = co.getCollarSize();
```

Comment: @user3349720: `Collar` is a instance variable of your `Dog` class, and `d.getCollar()` will return that `Collar` variable to the caller

Comment: but we use object reference variable to call methods right?? is object reference variable and instance variable same?? i mean using instance variables also we can call methods??

Comment: @user3349720 : What do you mean by `object reference variable`? You can invoke methods on any references

Comment: Please let me know if am wrong:  `private Collar theCollar;
    private int dogSize;
    public Dog(Collar collar, int size) {
        theCollar = collar;
        dogSize = size;
    }` Here we are declaring an instance variable Collar collar and in the constructor we are initializing that instance variable. and when we call d.getCollar().getCollarSize(); getCollar returns collar and using that we call the getCollarSize() method of Collar class.

Comment: And if in the constructor we dont initialize the Collar collar instance variable then it will throw null pointer exception or not initialized error right?? the chaining depends on what the method returns... right??

Comment: @user3349720 : Yes, that's correct. You got the point. Accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
object.firstMethod().secondMethod().thirdMethod()
```

*Execution is always goes from left to right*.
On `Object` `firstMethod()` is called which returns some `object` and on that `secondMethod()` is called which returns some `Object` and on that `thirdMethod()` is called and so on...

In your case `d.getCollar().getCollarSize()`
d is object of class Dog on which `getCollar()` method is called which returns instance of `Collar` on which again `getCollarSize()` is called.

This is called [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

> In your comment if I am not wrong you want to ask it is a normal
>   uninstantiated variable and how one can call method on it?

```
    Collar c = new Collar(3);
    Dog d = new Dog(c, 5);
```

In above two lines First you create Collar instance and Call Parameterised contructor of Dog
class.

```
private Collar theCollar;
private int dogSize;
public Dog(Collar collar, int size) {
    theCollar = collar;
    dogSize = size;
}
```

Here in above code you assign that instantiated object of Collar to `private Collar theCollar;`

Comment: `Collar c = new Collar();` it is an instance of class Collar yes i agree but how is Collar collar an instance?? its an instance variable i reckon?? [`public Dog(Collar collar, int size)`]

Comment: because getCollar() method returns collar which is an instance variable and not an object reference variable... So am bit confused there

Answer (score 0):

d.getCollar() return an object of type 'Collar' and you are invoking the second method getCollarSize() on this object.

Answer (score 0):

The same as this statements:

```
Collar co = d.getCollar();//invoke the getCollar method of a Dog object
int size = co.getCollarSize();//invoke the getCollarSize of a Collar object
```